# Axis client, omit empty tags from (RPC/encoded style) SOAP request xml

Tags: java, xml, soap, axis, soap-rpc-encoded

We have a SOAP web service from our vendor (we cannot change it) which uses "RPC/encoded" style. And we use Apache Axis (version 1.4) to generate and use the client.

There is an element in the request of one of the methods, which looks like this:

```
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CRD_EXPIRY" nillable="false" type="xsd:dateTime" />
```

So it is "omittable", but not "nillable". So when I leave this param empty (when we do not call `setCRD_EXPIRY` at all), I expect there will be no `CRD_EXPIRY` tag in request XML at all.

But Axis engine, still puts this tag in the request, with `nil="true"` attribute:

```
      <CRD_EXPIRY xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="xsd:dateTime"/>
```

Further, I have dug into the sources, and found these lines in `org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer` class, which seems to do the trick:

```
// . . .
if (propValue == null) {

    // . . .

    // if meta data says minOccurs=0, then we can skip
    // it if its value is null and we aren't doing SOAP
    // encoding.
    if (isOmittable && !isEncoded) {
        continue;
    }
}

context.serialize(qname,
                  null,
                  propValue,
                  xmlType, javaType);
// . . .
```

It looks like for "encoded" style web services empty parameters are always present in request XML with `nil` values. Even if they are not "nillable".

Am I true? If yes, why is it like this (does not look like a bug)?

And mainly, how can I achieve that empty params do not appear in request XML?

Thanks

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Sorry, it was a long time ago. Don't really remember. But I think not, I think we just moved from Apache Axis, to another library.